# What shall I do to prevent a change in one element to trigger a change in other element?

Tags: events, element, dart

In the ToolBar class of lib/tool_bar.dart

https://github.com/dzenanr/magic_boxes/blob/master/lib/tool_bar.dart

at https://github.com/dzenanr/magic_boxes there are two elements

InputElement itemNameInput;

SelectElement itemCategorySelect;

itemNameInput.onChange.listen((Event e) {

itemCategorySelect.onChange.listen((Event e) {

A change in itemCategorySelect triggers a change in itemNameInput!? This change complicates a use of the tool.

What shall I do to prevent a change in one element to trigger a change in other element?

In the tool, it happens when entering a new attribute for the selected concept:

A new attribute may be added to the selected concept by entering its name in the attribute field. Use the Enter key to see the name in the concept's attributes.
If you want to use characteristics different from those proposed,
change them first, then enter a name in the attribute field (I want to avoid this.)

Problem:
If you enter an attribute name first without using the Enter key, then change 
at least one of its characteristics (e.g., attribute category), the name appears 
in the concept's attributes but without a changed characteristic. 
Then, you must select it (by entering again its name) in order to apply the change.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a working solution:

change

itemNameInput.onChange.listen((Event e) {

to

itemNameInput.onKeyPress.listen((KeyboardEvent e) {

```
  if (e.keyCode != 13) return; // 13 is Enter key
```

In this way an attribute name appears in the concept's attributes only after the Enter key is presses.

However, in the Dart API doc, I have found out that the KeyboardEvent is deprecated.

http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/KeyboardEvent.html

"Note: The KeyboardEvent interface is deprecated in DOM Level 3 in favor of the new TextInput interface and the corresponding textinput event, which have improved support for alternate input methods."

I have not found TextInput interface nor textinput event!?